# Does a person have a biological lower and upper limit with the tone one can achieve with his/her voice?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I want to be better at singing and I'm taking voice lessons for that.

However, one of my main concerns is my voice range. I have a low voice and because of that, I can rarely find a song that doesn't have notes I can't reach. I often have to transpose a song a few notes lower so I could sing it comfortably.

Is this something I can train and train and can eventually reach any note, or am I limited by my genetics?

Comment: What kind of stuff are you singing? Solo performance? In a choir you obviously could just take the bass part but you potentially could make a _bass_ part for other songs or go down a whole octave. Modern pop music tends to be very high - the charts are full of girly-voiced men - but that doesn't mean nobody wants to listen to a man who sounds like a man!

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to the question is yes, to plus or minus a couple of notes. As the other answer states, even if the range becomes bigger, the outside sounds may not be particularly pleasant, especially dependent on the words sung. I've lost count of the number of times I've had to change the key of songs in different bands - it often makes a heck of a difference for the vocals, but not much for the instrumentalists. Often the 'original key' is just that - the one the song was written in - sometimes because that's what the writer could do, or where the idea came from, sometimes to just suit the tessitura of the person who it was written for. It doesn't make it the 'right' key. The right key for a singer is the one he sings it best in. Some songs have a small range, so it's no problem, but with others, get used to the fact that a change of key may be needed. Your tutor should be able and happy to do this for you.